# PyQGIS Smooth error: too many arguments

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, geometry

I'm trying to implement QgsGeometry.smooth() in my plugin as according to the API specifications.

[API Link here](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a5d61f4e676a6cd736114a079e5785c98)

Here is my code:

```
def lineSmooth(self, line):
    ''' Takes a line geometry and applies smooth
    '''
    iterations = int(self.dlg.smoothIterations.value())
    offset = float(self.dlg.smoothOffset.value())
    minDist = float(self.dlg.smoothMinDist.value())
    maxAngle = float(self.dlg.smoothMaxAngle.value())

    return line.smooth(iterations, offset, minDist, maxAngle)
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: QgsGeometry.smooth(int, float): too many arguments
```

When I print the parameter values I'm sending to the method:

```
(1, 0.25, -1.0, 180.0)
```

Now, I'm pretty new to Python and programming in general, and this is my first QGIS plugin, so I might be doing something silly.

Comment: You need a **try...except** clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I tried out this code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feat = layer.getFeatures().next()

geom = feat.geometry()

length = geom.length()

print length

new_geom = geom.smooth(1, 0.25)

print new_geom.exportToWkt()
```

and it worked; as it can be watched at next image (new_geom was exported in WKT format and it was visualized with QuickWKT plugin):

[image]

When it is necessary four parameters, you should use a **try...except** clause. In my particular case it worked nicely.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feat = layer.getFeatures().next()

geom = feat.geometry()

length = geom.length()

print length

try:
    new_geom = geom.smooth(1, 0.25, -1, 180)

except TypeError:
    pass

print new_geom.exportToWkt()
```

The new geometry (four parameters) is visualized in green color.

[image]